# Make WRITE_TRUNCATE and WRITE_APPEND dynamic in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam program that processes the file that comes in a GCS bucket and dumps the data in some BigQuery table. Depending on the file, I want to set the truncate or append operation. Can this be made dynamic or configurable?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say *"depending on file"*, you have some information about the file (to recognize which when to use `WRITE_TRUNCATE` and `WRITE_APPEND`) in your pipeline.

Easiest thing to do will be to split the input you're passing into BigQuery into two `PCollections` (by filtering) and pass each of them into appropriate BigQuery sink (one with `WRITE_TRUNCATE` and one with `WRITE_APPEND`).

You didn't mention if you use Java or Python, the **pseudocode** below is for Python, but it could be easily ported to Java SDK

```
files = (pipeline
        | 'Read files' >> beam.io.Read(Your_GCS_Source())
        )
files_to_truncate = (files 
         | beam.Filter(lambda file: filter_for_files_to_truncate()) 
         | beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(output_table, schema=output_schema, create_disposition=create_disposition, write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))
    )

files_to_append = (files
        | beam.Filter(lambda file: filter_for_files_to_append()) 
        | beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(output_table, schema=output_schema, create_disposition=create_disposition, write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need to write the entire file's data in a big query table...so basically what I mean is I have a generic program that takes as input a single file and dumps its data into big query...and im maintaining a config table from which I'm getting what all operations to perform on it...hence I must be able to apply append or truncate to the entire file depending on what my config says... P.S. I'm using Java as the language...

Comment: So you can just put this config table as a side input (additional pcollection) into the beam pipeline and use it to filter (split) your files

Comment: I don't want to split the file. 
And can you provide an example of the above because I don't think I can pass a side input while making WriteDisposition.

Comment: You don't have to split the file, you need to split collection of files into two collections - one which you want to save to BQ using truncate and other, which will use APPEND. Could you draw diagram of your pipeline, because I think we have different understanding of what you want to achieve?

Comment: "1" file --> Dataflow job --> output to BigQuery(Append/Truncate depends on config). How to do this?

Comment: I would push "file" along with "config" into the dataflow job (two inputs), which will then have split output, one for truncate and one for append. When you apply filter based on your config, file will enter either "TRUNCATE" BigQuerySink or "APPEND" BigQuerySink.
{"file", "config"} --> DataFlowJob --> Filter into two subsets {A, B}

then
{A} --> Write Truncate
{B} --> Write Append

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152389/discussion-between-rish0097-and-marcin-zablocki).

Comment: @rish0097 any progress on the pipeline?